# How to call the string value in canvas?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator, android-canvas

I have some stored value in String like:

```
Intent myIntent = getIntent(); 
Bundle b = myIntent.getExtras();
String a = b.getString("a");
```

I want to display this value on my canvas page:How to display it?I tried to do this:

```
canvas.drawText(a,apaint);
```

but it doesn`t work.Can you please help me..

Comment: What didn't work? What happened when you tried the above code? Did you get a compiler error? Did the app run? If so what happened?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set paint color first

```
paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
```

then draw text

```
canvas.drawText(a, x, y, paint);
```

`x` and `y` - origin coordinates.